# duplicating list after adding or removing a row

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview that is populated from an sql table. It works fine except for the fact that it duplicates all entrys when i try to delete a row or to insert a new one.

So before any changes it looks like

item 1

item 2

after inserting or deleting 1 row it becomes

item 1

item 2

item 1

item 2

I'm using fillData to set the adapter everytime the list changes.

It seems to work fine for the first call of fillData() but succesive calls just readd the whole list on top of the existine one.

Here is some code:

```
private void fillData() {   
int a=0;
todo = dbHelper.fetchAllTodos();        
startManagingCursor(todo);
todo.moveToFirst();  
while (!todo.isAfterLast()) {           
    String title=todo.getString(todo.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbTodoAdapter.KEY_SUMMARY));
    String detail=todo.getString(todo.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbTodoAdapter.KEY_DESCRIPTION));
    String priority=todo.getString(todo.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbTodoAdapter.KEY_CATEGORY));
    String alarm=todo.getString(todo.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbTodoAdapter.KEY_ALARM));
    if(alarm!=null) a=1; else a=0;
    if(priority.contains("Urgent"))             
        rd = new RowData(0, title, detail,a,alarm);
    if(priority.contains("Medium"))
        rd = new RowData(1, title, detail,a,alarm);
    if(priority.contains("Low"))
        rd = new RowData(2, title, detail,a,alarm);
    data.add(rd);
    todo.moveToNext();              
}       
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.todo_list_row, R.id.title, data);      
setListAdapter(adapter);        
getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);   
//adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

```
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {

  public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {               
          super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);          
      }              
  @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {    
      View view = convertView;
      ViewHolder holder=null;
      TextView title = null;
      TextView detail = null;
      ImageView i11=null;
      ImageView i12=null;
      TextView alarm=null;
      RowData rowData= getItem(position);
      if(convertView == null){               
         convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_list_row, null);
   holder = newViewHolder(convertView);                                 
         convertView.setTag(holder);                 
      }else{
       mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }
         title = holder.gettitle();
         title.setText(rowData.mTitle);
         detail = holder.getdetail();
                                                                                                    detail.setText(rowData.mDetail);              
         i11=holder.getImage();
         i11.setImageResource(imgid[rowData.mId]);
         i12=holder.getImageAl();
         i12.setImageResource(imgida[rowData.mIda]);
         alarm = holder.getalarm();
         alarm.setText(rowData.mAlarm);                
         return convertView;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the start of fillData(), do the following..

```
data.clear();
```